# How can I use C++ concepts with type_traits?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I want to abstract type interfaces and I am having a hard time to decide between the two C++ means of concepts and type_traits. Consider the follow scenario:

```cpp
template <typename T>
int foo(const T& t) { return t.size() + t.size(); }
```

The type `T` is requested to provide `int T::size() const`. For creating better error messages, increasing usability for user-defined types of the client and giving him a well-defined list of what an acceptable type must be capable of, a concept can be introduced:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept SizeHaving = requires(T t) {
    t.size();
}

template <SizeHaving T>
int foo(const T& t) { return t.size() + t.size(); }
```

But what if a client type *in principle* could fulfill the concept, but technically doesn't (and cannot be changed, as it may be part of a third-party library)? A *type_trait* could help out:

```cpp
struct Special {
   int Dimension() const; // logically identical to size(), but a different name
};

template <typename T>
struct Type_traits {
    static int size(const T& t) { return t.size(); }
};

template <> // user can provide the specialization for the custom type
struct Type_traits<Special> {
    static int size(const Special& c) { return c.Dimension(); }
};

template <typename T>
int foo(const T& t) {
    return Type_traits<T>::size(t) + Type_traits<T>::size(t);
}
```

If the standard implementation of `Type_trait` does not suit for a custom type (and no specialization is provided), there will be again rather unfortunate error messages. **How can I get concepts into the play?**
What I've tried is

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept SizeHaving = requires(T t) {
    Type_traits<T>::size(t);
}
```

but the expression constraint will be technically satisfied for *any* type, whether `Type_traits<T>::size()` can be explicitly instantiated or not, rendering this concept useless. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also constraint your traits:

```
template <typename T>
concept SizeHaving = requires(const T& t) {
    t.size(t);
};

template <typename T>
struct Type_traits
{
    auto size(const T& t) requires(SizeHaving<T>) { return t.size(); }
};

template <typename T>
concept TraitSizeHaving = requires(T t) {
    Type_traits<T>::size(t);
};

template <TraitSizeHaving T>
int foo(const T& t) {
    return Type_traits<T>::size(t) + Type_traits<T>::size(t);
}
```

And then specialize for your custom type:

```
struct Special {
   int Dimension() const; // logically identical to size(), but a different name
};

template <> // user can provide the specialization for the custom type
struct Type_traits<Special> {
    static int size(const Special& c) { return c.Dimension(); }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MoPEh5).

Note: `requires(SizeHaving<T>)` should be done on member, and not the class to allow specialization of the class.